# How to use %n formatter in format string

Tags: format-string

I recently saw a CTF challenge application (elf x86_64) on Linux environment, vulnerable to several attacks including format string, because the complexity of the full exploit, I don't want to say too much about, I saw someone who use something like the following as input for the format string attack:

`%130x%7$n`

What happens if I put the above payload as input for the vulnerable format string function? Does it write the value 130 hex in the seven position on the stack?

Comment: How formatting strings work is document - see for example [man 3 printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). As for the ctf - it is missing any kind of context, i.e. the formatting string by its own is not a problem.

Comment: "I saw an exploit in a document, but I won't tell you what it was. But anyway, based on that exploit, what will this random string do?" -- like Steffen said, we are missing context ...

Comment: consider the first owasp example code:

[link](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack) 

what happens if I put this %130x%7$n as payload?

Comment: This video might be helpful https://youtube.com/watch?v=F6UerHkVdLA , and I highly recommend the channel as well ([LiveOverflow](https://youtube.com/c/LiveOverflowCTF)) if you are interested in cybersecurity or penetration testing.

Comment: Also, please don't take this the wrong way, but the question should have included more context. Here is another great video about this: https://youtube.com/watch?v=53zkBvL4ZB4